# How good are the hematologic parameters (e,g, IL6 or others) in predicting which patients will develop a severe COVID-19 disease?

Tags: molecular-biology, pathology, hematology, coronavirus, infectious-diseases

Clinical implications of the hematologic profile of COVID-19 patients including cytokine storm, coagulation profile and thrombophilic complications are starting to be recognized. Hypercoagulability could be the potential cause of death due to COVID-19:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7585459/

How good is the hematologic profile, including hematologic markers (such as interleukins and others) in predicting if COVID-19 is severe, has mild manifestations or it is asymptomatic?

Answer (score 2):

A recent [pre-print](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.11.09.20228015v1.full.pdf) has studied this by measuring 86 accredited diagnostic parameters and plasma proteomes at 687 sampling points, in a cohort of 139 patients during hospitalisation.

> We identified 26 protein biomarkers and 14 routine diagnostic markers
> (Fig. 4a, Supp. Fig. SF20) that correlate with the time between the
> first sampling point and release from inpatient care. The proteomic
> signature associated with longer duration of inpatient treatment and
> hence more severe COVID-19 progression includes upregulated components
> of the complement system (C1QA, C1QB, C1QC) and reflects altered
> coagulation (KLKB1, PLG, SERPIND1) and inflammation (CD14, B2M,
> SERPINA3, CRP, GPLD1, PGLYRP2, AHSG).

They used a learning classifier to then predict survival in critically ill patients:

> In a last step, we established a machine learning model based on
> parenclitic networks52,53 (Methods) to predict survival in critically
> ill patients (WHO grade 7, n=49) from the proteome of the earliest
> single time point sample at WHO grade 7 for a particular patient. On
> the test subjects (the data of whom were excluded when training the
> machine learning model), high prediction accuracy was achieved, with
> AUC = 0.81 for the receiver-operating characteristic (ROC) curve. Of
> note, the model correctly predicted survival or adverse outcome weeks
> in advance (median time from prediction to outcome 39 days,
> interquartile range 16 - 64 days).

The 'predictive power' can be captured (not in a perfect way) by the AUC value - a value of 0 has the worst power to separate patients and 1 has perfect power, so 0.81 is pretty good overall. I haven't read the paper fully, but from a brief scan it looks as though their methodology is at least reasonably sound.